# c++ - Como retornar um valor para uma janela anterior em Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, gui, return, inteiros

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um projeto onde terei muitas chamadas de novas janelas e preciso recuperar um valor dessas janelas para a janela principal (MainWindow). O Problema é que se torna impossível de se pegar o valor retornado pois, ao fechar a nova janela, o valor se perde com seu destrutor e nao se retorna para a janela principal.

EDIT2:

Meu código da nova janela onde retorno um valor (tamveicdialog.cpp):

```
int TamVeicDialog::getLargura(){
    return this->largura;
}

void TamVeicDialog::on_ButtonSalvar_clicked(){
    this->close();
}
```

Chamada da minha nova janela na janela principal:

```
void mainwindow::on_ButtonTamVeic_clicked(){

    TamVeicDialog *tamVeic = new TamVeicDialog();
    tamVeic->setFixedSize(696, 368);
    tamVeic->reset(); // seta alguns valores de atributos da nova janela // 
    tamVeic->show();
    int larg = tamVeic->getLargura();

    qDebug() << "Largura retornada: " << larg;
}
```

A idéia é ao clicar em salvar na janela TamVeic, ela retorne o valor de largura para MainWindow. Alguém saberia como retornar este valor para a minha Mainwindow? Grato desde já.

Obs: Por mais que a minha janela tenha 'dialog' em sua declaração, ela é do tipo QWidget, acho que esta dúvida pdoe ter causado problemas pra entender o meu problema.

Comment: 1) O destrutor não é chamado no seu código (onde está o delete correspondente ao new?); 2) A maneira como o seu código funciona é a adequada para fazer isto, não há porque não funcionar, considerando que você está copiando o valor de largura para um inteiro no formulário atual (para que ele mantenha-se após o uso da função é necessário um membro e não uma variável local).

Comment: Na minha nova janela, o usuário realiza uma operação e clica em um botão "Salvar", ao clicar, a janela se fecha, acredito que o destrutor seja chamado no momento que a janela fecha, e desta forma, nao consigo retornar um valor para a janela anterior. Não entendi o que quis dizer com um 'membro' . Obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: Yuri, da maneira como seu código está estruturado o objeto não será liberado da memória (e isso causa um vazamento de memória), até porque caso sua memória fosse liberada (e o destrutor chamado) você não conseguiria acessar "tamVeic->getLargure();" isso geraria um erro em tempo de execução. Você deve deletar o objeto que foi instanciado com new obrigatoriamente e peço por gentileza que poste o código de "TamVeicDialog" para que talvez consigamos te auxiliar.

Comment: Editei o meu post, o código de TamVeic é muito grande, então seria inviável postá-lo por completo, desculpe. Mas no entanto que importa neste caso é o retorno da variável largura para a janela Pai (MainWindow). A intenção era que ao clicar no botão salvar da nova janela, ela retornasse o valor modificado de largura para a tela anterior. Espero que eu tenha conseguido explicar um pouco melhor.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Teria algum exemplo utilizando signals e slots ou este modal? pesquisei em alguns foruns e a maior parte dos exemplos são de Mainwindow para as janelas filhas.

Comment: O `show` não "trava" a janela aberta para o usuário digitar. Utilize `exec` após o show, assim a janela fica em um próprio Loop até o usuário fechá-la. Depois, é só pegar o valor do campo desejado e deletar a instância manualmente (usando `delete` no ponteiro previamente alocado com `new`). Você também pode verificar o retorno do `exec` pra saber se o usuário cancelou a edição. Dá uma olhada nos exemplos de `MsgBox`. Estou sem tempo de preparar uma resposta, mas a ideia é por aí.

Comment: Esqueci de mencionar o detalhes de que mesmo com 'dialog no nome', a minha classe da janela herda de um QWidget, acho que isto pode ter causado problemas pra entender a minha questão. Criarei um QDialog e tentarei utilizar o exec() do modo que  falou. Obrigado @LuizVieira pela resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O meu problema era de simples resolução. Adicionei a linha `tamVeic->exec();` após a chamada de `tamVeic->show();`, o que permitiu que o valor fosse retornado para a janela principal. Também tive que mudar o tipo (a herança) de `QWidget` para `QDialog` para poder utilizar o método `exec();`. Esse método trava a execução de quem o chamou até que a janela seja fechada pelo usuário.